# Is there a limit for the S query in Gerrit-Rest-Api?

Tags: python, api, rest, gerrit

Sorry for my unknowledge about Gerrit Rest API, the documentation is not very easy to understand for me.

I'm trying to fetch alot of data about code-changes with Gerrit.
I'm using the S query to refresh to the next page, but it always seems to stop at 19500. I can
never see more than 20 000 changes.
Is there some internal limit or am I doing things wrong?
This is how my API looks atm, the next api request when S=20000 is empty, even if I have some crazy
timerange such as 1 year

```
 def __init__(self, baseurl):
        self.baseurl = baseurl

    def changes(self, PLATFORM, query, start=None, limit=None, options=None):
        
        
        
        username="******"
        password="**********"
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username=username,password=password)
        params = {"q": query}
        
        if start is not None:
            params["-S"] = start
        if limit is not None:
            params["n"] = limit
        if options is not None:
            params["o"] = options
        if(PLATFORM != "https://review.opendev.org"):
            res = requests.get(f"{self.baseurl}/a/changes/", params=params, auth=auth)
        else:
            res = requests.get(f"{self.baseurl}/changes/", params=params,)
        print(f"fetched [{res.status_code}]: {res.url}", file=sys.stderr)
        #print(res.text[4:])
        error_code = res.status_code
        return json.loads(res.text[4:]),error_code

    @staticmethod
    def generateJSON(JSON_response):
        """
        Generates and saves the data as a JSON names out.json
        """
        # Here we're just dumping all the results as a JSON document on
        # stdout.
        file_name = "JSON/out.json"
        with open(file_name, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(JSON_response, json_file, indent=4)
        return

    def requestAPICall(url,PLATFORM,DATE_1,DATE_2,SET_TIME_1,SET_TIME_2):
        """
        does API stuff
        """
        response = Gerrit(PLATFORM)
        all_results = []
        date_string = 'since:"'+DATE_2+" "+SET_TIME_2+'" before:"'+DATE_1+" "+SET_TIME_1+'"'
        print(date_string)
        start = 0
        while True:
            res,error = response.changes(
                PLATFORM,
                date_string,
                limit=5000,
                start=start
                )
            if not res:
                break
            all_results.extend(res)
            if not res[-1].get("_more_changes"):
                break
            start += len(res)
        Gerrit.generateJSON(all_results)
        return error
```

This is how it looks
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YQcn.png)

I have tried the no-limit parameter but it seems have been removed. I have also tried using pygerrit2 but it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I solved it by restarting the search with some algo finding the latest date